# Make field of child-record required for user-input

Tags: acumatica

Along with an SOInvoice that is created with "Prepare Invoice" in the SOOrder Screen, I insert a child-record which is empty at first.
When the user then enters some data manually one field of my child-record should become required.
I already have this Code, that works when the Tab of my child-record is open, but it doesn't work when another Tab is open.

```
    public void _(Events.RowPersisting<MyChild> e)
    {
        MyChild element = e.Row as MyChild;
        if (element != null && element.MyField == null)
        {
            e.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<MyChild.myField>(
                e.Row, 
                null, 
                new PXSetPropertyException(
                    Messages.MyFieldIsEmpty, 
                    typeof(MyChild.myField).Name
                )
            );
            e.Cancel = true;                
        }
    }
```

I also tried that:

```
    public SelectFrom<MyChild>.Where<MyChild.myField.IsNotNull.And<MyChildElements.refNbr.Contains<ARInvoice.refNbr.FromCurrent>>>.View MyChilds;

    public void _(Events.RowPersisting<ARInvoice> e)
    {
        var hasChildren = MyChilds.Select().Count > 0;
        if (!hasChildren)
        {
            e.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<MyChild.myField>(
                e.Row,
                null,
                new PXSetPropertyException(
                    Messages.MyFieldIsEmpty,
                    typeof(MyChild.myField).Name
                )
            );
            e.Cancel = true;
            throw new PXException(Messages.MyFieldIsEmpty);
        }
}
```

It runs but doesn't stop the save action or show an error at all.

The goal is to have the required mark on the Tab and on the Field, no matter which Tab is currently active.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the field as required in the code under rowSelected. For example,

```
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>(e.Cache, requirePO);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<SOOrder.contactID>(e.Cache, requireContact);
```